# Python Pandas Create Columns Using Row and Add Values When Criteria is Met

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a program, and a part of it needs to convert rows into columns.

Here is what my CSV file looks like:

```
ID   | Items  | Status
1      Item1    Submitted
1
1      Item2    Pending
2      Item1    Submitted
3      Item1    Submitted
```

I want to achieve this using pandas. True if submitted and false if pending:

```
ID | Item1 | Item2
1    true    false
2    true    false
3    true    false
```

I tried using `.dropna().unique()` since I have rows with null values and I don't want them to become a column.

Comment: To clarify, the second row is meant to be with null values, right? Where the rest of `false` for `Item2` come from in your example? Or is it just you to picture how it might look like on extended data?

Comment: @n.shabankin yes, the second row is null, and I don't want it to become a column like
id | item1 | Nan | item2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper column `new`, remove rows for non matched dictionary values (`Submitted`,`Pending`) and last pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = (df.assign(new=df['Status'].map({'Submitted':True, 'Pending':False}))
        .dropna(subset=['new'])
        .pivot('ID','Items','new'))
print (df)
Items Item1  Item2
ID                
1      True  False
2      True    NaN
3      True    NaN
```

Comment: And to achieve `Item2` column filled with `False` you may use `df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks, jezrael, and n.shabankin. I was able to resolve my problem using your answers as references.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original csv is like this:

```
id,items,status
1,itemA,submitted
1,,
1,itemB,pending
2,itemA,submitted
3,itemA,submitted
```

And also assuming you want the resulting/output csv to look like this (you can easily read the output using pandas without further processing):

```
id,itemA,itemB
1,true,false
2,true,false
3,true,false
```

Then, the code you want is this:

```
import io
from collections import OrderedDict

data_array = []
data_array_new = []
unique_column = []
unique_row = OrderedDict()

file_object = io.open('dataset.txt', 'r')
header_line = file_object.readline().strip()
while True:
    line = file_object.readline().strip()
    if line != '':
        data_array.append(line)
    else:
        break
file_object.close()

for x in data_array:
    bad_line = False
    for y in x.split(","):
        if len(y) == 0:
            bad_line = True
    if not bad_line:
        data_array_new.append(x)
        unique_column.append(x.split(",")[1])
        if x.split(",")[2] == "submitted":
            evaluation = "true"
        else:
            evaluation = "false"
        try:
            unique_row[x.split(",")[0]][x.split(",")[1]] = evaluation
        except:
            unique_row[x.split(",")[0]] = OrderedDict()
            unique_row[x.split(",")[0]][x.split(",")[1]] = evaluation

unique_column = sorted(list(set(unique_column)))

for key, value in unique_row.items():
    for x in unique_column:
        try:
            unique_row[key][x]
        except:
            unique_row[key][x] = "false"

output_string = header_line.split(",")[0]+","+",".join(unique_column) + "\n"

for key, value in unique_row.items():
    output_string = output_string + key
    for x in unique_column:
        output_string = output_string + "," + value[x]
    output_string = output_string + "\n"

f = open("new_dataset.txt", "w")
f.write(output_string)
f.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).